# Refresh all elements that their ids are partly equal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage which contains while loop, i have assign an id to each element inside the while loop, here is an example:

< tagname id="show_div_1">< /tagname>

The "show_id_" is static but "1" is dynamic which comes from loop and it will be increase to 2,3,4 ...etc.

Anyone knows how to select such elements using javascript or jquery?

Or is there any alternative way to do so?

Comment: You need to know how to iterate over each id using the loop?

Comment: Which answer suits you the best?

Comment: both answers are correct thanks, but "Eric Martinez" provided me more information, now i m stuck which one to accept, yours or "Eric Martinez"?

Comment: Accept Eric's answer if it suited you more than mine then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Jquery contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Like this

```
$('tagname[id*="show_div_"]').each(function() { 
   // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('tagname[id^="show_div_"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just put them in the same class?

i.e.

```
 <tagname class="something">
```

then

```
$(.something)
```

Comment: your answer is correct thanks, but the situation is different and it won't work for me, thanks again.

Comment: coz it is already inside a parent div, and that parent div contains many other childs and i want to select only specific childs